# How could this simple pointer equality test fail?

Tags: c++, pointers, equality

```
void FileManager::CloseFile(File * const file)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_OPEN_FILES; ++i)
    {
        if ((_openFiles[i] == file) == true)
        {
            _openFiles[i] == NULL;
        }
    }
...
```

_openFiles is a private member of FileManager and is just an array of File *'s
When the exact same test is performed in the Immediate window i get a result of 1!?!

**EDIT** the == true was added purely as a sanity check!!

Comment: if I may offer a suggestion: I think you really should be using a more advanced data structure here.  A hash of some kind would prevent the need for the search every time that function is called, and I can only imagine that there are other such functions on a "manager" class such as this.  Manager classes are also something of a code smell in many cases...

Comment: The class is in it's infancy, and hashing is on the list! But thanks for the suggestion as it confirms my oppinions..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
 _openFiles[i] == NULL;
```

should that be

```
 _openFiles[i] = NULL;
```

?

Comment: So the comparison WASN'T failing?
I assumed that "Immediate window" meant you were doing this in some kind of debugger -- did you not step through the program?

Also: compile with full warnings (and even warnings as errors) in order to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: Q: What did we learn today?  A1: The fewer characters the fix, the harder to find the bug. A2: Never, ever, do assignments inside conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough karma to add a comment, but if **cma**'s answer was was correct (that a conditional should be an assignment), then I wish the original post hadn't been fixed, or at least had a note that it had been fixed.  I stared at it a long time, trying to find the bug, before giving up and reading the answers.

To anyone who can, feel free to delete this "answer".

Comment: Yea... I was wondering the same thing. I couldn't for the life of me figure out what was wrong with it because of that. :/